# Mongo geoNear Aggregation Pipeline - 'near' field must be point

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geolocation, mongodb-query, geospatial

I am using a Mongo pipeline within an aggregation lookup on 2 collections, Locations and Places.

I am trying to return all the places which these locations are near.

> The error I get is 'MongoError: 'near' field must be point'

I believe this is because I am trying to use the $point variable in the pipeline from the let in the lookup and I am doing something wrong here. All the answers I see on here have static coordinates but I want to use the ones from the lookup.

This is the code I have:

```
   return await this.placeModel.aggregate([{
      $lookup : {
        from : "locations",
        let : {point : "location.coordinates"},
        pipeline: [  {
          $geoNear: {
            distanceField: "distance",
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: "$point" },
            maxDistance: 20,
            spherical: true
          }
        }],
        as : "places"
      }
    }]);
  }
```

I have a mongoose Place model and Location model. Each model has a GeoJson point that looks like this:

```
location: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: []
  },
```

How do I reference the point properly if at all possible.

Comment: `let` expression must be with `$`. `let : {point : "$location.coordinates"}`

Comment: Same error unfortunately

Comment: Yes I had spotted that one and corrected it but still had the same error

Comment: Ok so I found jira regarding this [issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38716). Till now it is not possible to use `$geoNear` with the `$lookup` pipeline.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when just using $geoNear by itself.  No clue how to resolve it.  Here's my code:

collectionName.aggregate([{$geoNear: {near: {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [req.query.longitude, req.query.latitude]}, distanceField: 'dist', maxDistance: (Number(req.query.distance)+2)*1609.344, spherical: true}}])